# PHP/MYSQL: Display data from MySQL to PHP table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a question to ask regarding on my current project. From the question above, I want to display data to my PHP table is same like this:

```
-------  ------  -------
   1       2        3
-------  ------  -------
   4       5        6      
-------  ------  -------
   7       8             
-------  ------  -------
```

Currently, I have only 8 data. The problem is, `<td>` at no 9 still appear although data doesn't exist.

Below is my current code.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM factory ORDER BY Fac_ID ASC";
                if($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
                    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
                        echo "<table class='table table-bordered' bgcolor='#ffffff' width='50%'>";
                        $td=0;
                            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                              if ($td==0){
                                echo "<tr>"; 
                              }
                              echo "<td>" . $row['Fac_ID'] . "</td>";
                              $td++;
                              if ($td==3){
                                echo "</tr>";
                                $td=0;
                              }

                            }
                            echo "</tbody>";                            
                        echo "</table>";
                        // Free result set
                        mysqli_free_result($result);
                    } else{
                        echo "<p class='lead'><em>No records were found.</em></p>";
                    }
                } else{
                    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
                }
```

How to make sure that `<td>` will appear when there is existing data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two side comments about your code style:

1) Try to avoid using `echo` with static HTML content - disable PHP instead.

2) Try to separate your database logic from HTML - code will be much clean.

```
$rows = [];

if ($result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM factory ORDER BY Fac_ID ASC"))
{
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $rows[] = $row;
    }
}

$rows_chunked = array_chunk($rows, 3);


?>
<table class="table table-bordered" bgcolor="#ffffff" width="50%">
<?php

foreach ($rows_chunked as $rows)
{
    ?><tr><?php

    foreach ($rows as $row)
    {
        ?><td><?php echo $row['Fac_ID'] ?></td><?php
    }

    echo str_repeat('<td></td>', 3 - count($rows));

    ?></tr><?php
}
?>
</table>
```

Comment: Kudos for separating the logic and presentation. I had a little trouble accomplishing that in my answer because procedural coding is so dang clunky. Two suggestions for **your** style: `<?php foreach($rows_chunked as $row):?>` and `<?= $row[‘Fac_ID’] ?>`  Keep php limited to one line and avoid braces because it’s hard to match up.

Comment: FYI, your solution correctly applies the `<tr>` tag, but it doesn’t look like it finishes out the missing `<td>` column(s).

Comment: @Tim Morton, first comment - I have no idea why do describe your answer under the my answer. Second comment - updated. However, table was valid without this modification.

Comment: first comment is acknowledging you separated logic from presentation better than I; I wish I had accomplished that

Answer (score 0):

Excuse me, 
Is there a 9th  `<td>` on there or is a data that does not exist? 
so, what the 9th data is? `null`? or `''`?

Comment: This is a comment, not a question

Comment: I just can't understand his question.

Comment: Ok, I get it, you cant comment as you have  < 50 Rep, Ill remove my downvote

Comment: I think it is more cautious to answer the question then answer it.
Finding the nature of the problem is often more important than answering the question.
I really can't comment...
Thank you for your understanding.

Answer (score 0):

> If your data doesn't naturally fill all the cells of your table, you should question whether a table is the right way to display it.

CSS can display it with a little bit of tweaking, without having to worry about splitting the results into rows; run example for plain html representation:

```css
.lined {
    border-top-style: dashed;
    border-bottom-style: dashed;
    margin-top: -3px;
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    


<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-3">Page Column 1</div>
  <div class="col-sm-3">Page Column 2</div>
  <div class="col-sm-3">Page Column 3</div>
  <div class="col-sm-3">Page Column 4</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="row">
    
      <div class="col-sm-4 lined">1</div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 lined">2</div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 lined">3</div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 lined">4</div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 lined">5</div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 lined">6</div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 lined">7</div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 lined">8</div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
  <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
</div>
```

All you need to do is incorporate your data into the html:

```php
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM factory ORDER BY Fac_ID ASC";

if(!$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)){ echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link); }

$rows = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
  $rows[] = $row;
}
mysqli_free_result($result);

?>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-3">Page Column 1</div>
  <div class="col-sm-3">Page Column 2</div>
  <div class="col-sm-3">Page Column 3</div>
  <div class="col-sm-3">Page Column 4</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="row">

    <?php foreach($rows as $r): ?>
      <div class="col-sm-4 lined"><?= $r['Fac_ID'] ?></div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>

    <?php if(sizeof($rows) == 0): ?>
      <p class='lead'><em>No records were found.</em></p>
    <?php endif; ?>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
  <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
</div>
```